# Stopping website with powerShell script

Tags: iis, powershell, windows-server-2008

Ive got a script for stopping a site:

```
param($HostName = "localhost", $SiteName)

$server = $HostName
$siteName = $SiteName
$iis = [ADSI]"IIS://$server/W3SVC"
$site = $iis.psbase.children | where { $_.keyType -eq "IIsWebServer" -AND $_.ServerComment -eq $siteName}
$site.start()

# SIG # Begin signature block ...
```

But when i run the script on a server with high security policies i get this error:

```
The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "Unknown error (0x80005000)".
At D:\DeploymentScripts\Common\StopSite.ps1:6 char:8
+ $site = <<<<  $iis.psbase.children | where { $_.keyType -eq "IIsWebServer" -AND $_.ServerComment -eq $siteName}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

From what I have read this might occur if i don't have access to the IIS , but im running the script as admin, should that not grant me the access i need ?

Does the webadministration module give more access rights ?
I don't import this since i didn't have to do this on the other servers, if i need to import the webadministration there is another problem, when i try i get a error saying the WebAdministrationAliases.ps1 is not digitally signed...

I have tested the script on other servers with no problem, but this one got more strict policies as mentioned above, and its not a option to change the policies.

Im running this on a Windows server 2008 R2, with IIS 7.5.

Comment: Have you tried the [PowerShell IIS module](http://www.iis.net/download/powershell)? Check out [Stop-Website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790607.aspx).

Comment: the powershell iis module you are linking to is a snap-in for iss 7.0,
and im using 7.5 which uses modules, and isnt that iis module the same as webadmin module ?

Comment: It also applies to IIS 7.5, http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/429/installing-the-iis-powershell-snap-in/

Comment: Tried to install the snap-in but it said it was not supported on the current operating system

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Stop-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
Start-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
```

Comment: I have problems with the "Import-Module WebAdministration" if i run it it says thats its already imported: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx), but if i run: "Import-Module -Name webadministration" i get the not digitally signed error. And Stop-WebSite is not recognized as a command

Comment: What is your execution policy (Get-ExecutionPolicy)? You should probably set it to the appropriate level before calling import-module.

Comment: My execution policy is AllSigned

Comment: Try "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted", then try to import the webadministration module.

Comment: I tested with RemoteSigned now, and the the message was that its default imported as stated in my first comment to this answer. So that rules out my webadministration package theory...

Comment: @Roise After set executionpolicy as remotesigned you need to close and re-open powershell console (run as administrator for working with webadministrator module), then `import-module webadministration`.

Comment: @Christian When i do this i get no message after i import the module, but i still get the same error when running my own script, so it still seems like i cant fetch any of my websites from IIS. The Stop-WebSite worked though...

Comment: Your script is not affected by webadministration module. Change your script for using `stop-website`!

Comment: Also, if it's no available you need to run the following to INSTALL the WebAdministration Modules.  

Add-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools

see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137154/738895

Answer (score 7):

Based on David's Answer:

In recent version of Windows (10, 2016, and later), you need to import IISAdministration instead of WebAdministration

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
Stop-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
Start-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
```

For older version of Windows and IIS, you need to do

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Stop-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
Start-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
```

Read More:

1- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets

2- https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery