# Import-Module WebAdministration wont load from script but does from command line

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5, web-administration

I'm coming onto a project that uses `PowerShell` to script the build.  The build makes use of the `WebAdministration` module to manage the local IIS instance.  When I run the build script the following error is thrown when trying to import `WebAdministration`.

> Error: 06/29/2016 17:28:35: At
>   C:\dev\src\nib-ravendb\build\ConfigureIis.ps1:10 char:1 +
>   Import-Module WebAdministration + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~
>   [<<==>>] Exception: The specified module 'WebAdministration' was not
>   loaded because no valid module file was fo und in any module
>   directory. ERROR: 1

How ever when I run `Import-Module WebAdministration` at the `PowerShell` command line the module is imported and I can use features from it. Subsequently running the build script still fails.

I have `IIS 7.5` and `PowerShell 4`

Does anyone have an idea why this import would be failing in the script but not at the command line, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end there was a problem something, possibly chocolatey?, was truncating `$env:PSModulePath` to the first entry, this is why the script was working if I typed it in but not in the script.

I found it by logging `$env:PSModulePath` at different points in the scripts that I was running.

I worked around it by reordering the entries in `$env:PSModulePath`.

Have a look at @Richard's answer for some other good suggestions.

Answer (score 26):

For servers you need to install the role `Management Tools` under `Web Server (IIS)` to use the `WebAdministration` module. To see if you have the module available use `Get-Module -ListAvailable`.

For `Windows 7` to `10` you will need to install the feature `IIS Management Scripts and tools` under `Internet Information Services` >> `Web Management Tools`.

You could try manually locating the `WebAdministration` .psd1 file and then import it. Use `$env:psmodulepath` to help locate where your modules are stored then run:

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\WebAdministration.psd1'
```

If `Server 2008` you could try the following but this may not work on 2012 and upwards:

```
Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration
```

**Note** You will need to run the script with administrator rights to be able to load the `WebAdministration` module with `Import-Module` or `Add-PSSnapin`.

Also check that you have `PowerShell`'s execution Policy set to `Unrestricted`:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

You might want to see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700660/add-pssnapin-webadministration-in-windows7).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Richard.  Unfortunately I have the Web Management Tools installed and WebAdministration come up when I list available modules.  I can even use it from the shell.  Just when I run the script it can't be imported.  Any idea on that?

Comment: @Klee I have updated my question with some things you could try.

Comment: thanks.  The first answer would have likely worked.  The other two I had already tried.  In the end there was a problem, possibly with chocolatey?, that was truncating $env:PSModulePath to the first entry, this is why the script was working if I typed it in but not in the script. I worked around it by reordering the entries in $env:PSModulePath Thanks heaps for you help.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same situation, i've fixed it installing the Windows Feature Web-Scripting-Tools on W2016 Server:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Windows 10) I was using Powershell 7 and this simply refused to install the WebAdministration module, despite it being present in Windows Features.

Using a previous version of PS: e.g. Developer PowerShell for VS worked.